# Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Моя библиотека:

```
// Components
import { ModalContext, ModalConsumer, connectModalConsumer, ModalProvider } from './src/components/ModalsManager/ModalContext';
import ModalRoot from './src/components/ModalsManager/ModalRoot';

export { 
  ModalContext, 
  ModalConsumer, 
  connectModalConsumer,
  ModalProvider,
  ModalRoot,
};
```

В проекте пишу:

```
import { ModalProvider, ModalRoot } from 'livedune-react-components';
```

Все нормально (вроде бы) импортируется, например console.log(ModalProvider):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, если я пишу:

```
  render() {
    console.log(ModalProvider);
    return (
      <ModalProvider>
        ...
      </ModalProvider>
    );
  }
```

То получаю ошибку:

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
    at invariant (index_bundle.js:1244)
    at createFiberFromElement (index_bundle.js:21586)
    at reconcileSingleElement (index_bundle.js:23364)
    at reconcileChildFibers (index_bundle.js:23468)
    at reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime (index_bundle.js:23589)
    at reconcileChildren (index_bundle.js:23580)
    at finishClassComponent (index_bundle.js:23714)
    at updateClassComponent (index_bundle.js:23683)
    at beginWork (index_bundle.js:24058)
    at performUnitOfWork (index_bundle.js:26057)
```

Как такое может быть? В консоль выводит класс, почему я вижу эту ошибку?

Код ModalProvider - https://pastebin.com/REUweQkQ

Comment: а можно код этого компонента?

Comment: видимо `render` что-то не то возвращает

Comment: https://pastebin.com/REUweQkQ @ThisMan - код ModalProvider

Comment: Попробуйте изменить `export class ModalProvider` на `export default class ModalProvider` . https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332#issuecomment-336925116

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, не, не помогает.